# How to index into an R raster brick with lat and lon

Tags: r, indexing, raster

I have constructed a raster brick where each layer represents a mean annual temperature map of the globe. The raster brick looks like this:

```
> x
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 360, 720, 259200, 110  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/kirkw/R_code/rgis/test.grd 
names       :   layer.1,   layer.2,   layer.3,   layer.4,   layer.5,   layer.6,   layer.7,   layer.8,   layer.9,  layer.10,  layer.11,  layer.12,  layer.13,  layer.14,  layer.15, ... 
min values  : -57.59665, -56.89876, -57.92206, -55.95920, -57.09456, -55.45393, -55.38048, -57.27017, -56.05618, -56.92603, -57.68953, -55.23584, -56.70047, -56.50427, -56.72116, ... 
max values  :  30.52231,  30.49426,  29.96689,  30.05002,  30.13025,  30.08621,  29.73001,  30.27164,  30.00519,  30.15961,  30.15723,  30.53934,  30.00043,  30.47162,  30.45111, ...
```

I'd like to be able to extract a vector by cell location that gives me a time series of that cell. I have been able to use the row and column numbers like this:

```
x[1, 1, ]
 layer.1   layer.2   layer.3   layer.4   layer.5   layer.6   layer.7  layer.8   layer.9
[1,] -14.92191 -16.13638 -14.39139 -15.55865 -14.23444 -14.64407 -13.99429 -13.8139 -14.96927
      layer.10  layer.11  layer.12  layer.13  layer.14  layer.15  layer.16  layer.17  layer.18
[1,] -14.28351 -15.20233 -15.07458 -13.19043 -14.15805 -13.78281 -14.42188 -14.89151 -14.91458
      layer.19  layer.20  layer.21  layer.22  layer.23  layer.24  layer.25  layer.26  layer.27
```

However, i'd like to extract data by lat and lon, but so far, have not come up with an approach to accomplish is. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can come up with a solution using functions such as `raster::crop`, `raster::extract`, and/or `raster::stackSelect`

Comment: Additional to `raster::extract`, you can take a look at `raster::cellFromXY`, `raster::colFromX` and `raster::rowFromY`